# "A quote of an American writer" vs. "a quote from an American writer

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me if both sentences below mean the same thing and are perfectly natural.

> The quote you just read is **of** an American writer.
>
> The quote you just read is **from** an American writer.

I've tried finding answers on the internet but wasn't able yo find one. I've also asked a friend of mine, a native English speaker, and they said both are correct, but *from* sounds better.

I'd like to know what other native speakers have to say about that and if there are contexts where both are perfectly natural.

Comment: _Quote_ is a variant of _quotation_, usually used with _from_. "I am quoting from [the works of] Shakespeare".

Answer (score 2):

I agree with your friend, that "from" sounds more natural, but both are correct.

The first feels only *kinda* correct because it's correct to use "of an American writer" immediately after the word "quote", so shifting it to the back sounds *kinda* correct.

> You just read a quote of an American writer.

I can't explain why this version is natural, while the original isn't, nor why "from" can be used naturally in both ways.

Comment: "Of" prepositional phrases do not frequently occur with the verb "be", whereas "to be from" (a place or source) is quite common.